# ReverseEngineeringGenerator in Entity Framework Core 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, reverse-engineering, scaffolding

Based on [this article](https://romiller.com/2017/02/13/ef-core-1-1-run-reverse-engineer-from-code/) by Mr Rowan Miller I want to use EF Core scaffolding system by code.

```
// Add base services for scaffolding
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddScaffolding()
    .AddLogging();

// Add database provider services
var provider = new SqlServerDesignTimeServices();
provider.ConfigureDesignTimeServices(serviceCollection);

var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

var generator = serviceProvider.GetService<ReverseEngineeringGenerator>();
var options = new ReverseEngineeringConfiguration
{
    ConnectionString = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=true",
    ProjectPath = @"C:\temp\",
    ProjectRootNamespace = "My.Namespace"
};

generator.GenerateAsync(options).Wait();
```

But it **does not work** with latest EF Core 2.1.

Can anyone help me to update the code? (an updated article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for 2.1 is available here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/master/src/GUI/ReverseEngineer20/EFCoreReverseEngineer.cs

```
var scaffolder = serviceProvider.GetService<IReverseEngineerScaffolder>();
var scaffoldedModel = scaffolder.ScaffoldModel(...
var filePaths = scaffolder.Save(scaffoldedModel,...
```

Comment: Can you update your link? because your link is broken. Do you have `ReverseEngineer` API yet?